How to replace only first occurrence in Word doc. Using Net, C# and OpenXML and OpenXmlPowerTools
I have this Net project and have to replace some words in a Word document by using OpenXml-Sdk and OpenXml-PowerTools. Everything works fine, except that I don't know how to replace only the first occurrence of a word, that repeats itself in the document.
I'm using OpenXmlRegex.Replace(content, regex, replacement, null) and know that the last parameter can be a callback that, if returning false, the replacement wont occur.
I just don't know how to write that callback so that it returns true only first time and false after that.
Can anybody suggest how to write the callback just to return true only for its first execution; then false after that?
This is an example of the use of the callback, but from the Match method. Could not find an example for the Replace method:
int count = OpenXmlRegex.Match(content, regex, (element, match) => Console.WriteLine("Example ...{0}", match.Value)

This is the definition of the Replace method (and its lambda callback) per its documentation:
public static int Replace(
‎    IEnumerable <XElement> content,
‎    Regex regex,
‎    string replacement,
‎    Func<XElement, Match, bool> doReplacement)

Many thanks in advance and bye ...

I think I found an answer to my situation ...
So, what I wanted is for OpenXmlRegex.Replace to just do one replacement, even if there are more than one occurrence of the word to replace.
Here it is how to execute the method if you don't mind it replacing all the ocurrences:
int count = OpenXmlRegex.Replace(content, regex, replacement, null);

That null at the end is where the callback should be. No callback, all replacements are made.
Here is how to write the method and callback if you want just the first occurrence to be replaced:
int count = OpenXmlRegex.Replace(content, regex, replacement, (element, match) => ReplaceMatch(match));

This is the way I wrote the callback:
private Match? _last_match; 
private bool ReplaceMatch(Match match)
{
    if (_last_match is null)
    {
        _last_match = match;
        return true;           // return true to make the replacement 
    }

    // if you do a match for *another* word, start again 
    if (_last_match.Value != match.Value)
    {
        _last_match = match;
        return true;
    }

    return false;            // return false to not make the replacement
}

Maybe it could be written more elegantly, but I tested it and it works.
Thanks and bye ...
